# If a file is present move another file in another folder

Tags: powershell, batch-file

in a particular folder I have files created with random name for example:

*file1.xml
file2.xml*

when these files are succesfully created, a .ack file is created.

So I will have

*file1.xml
file1.ack
file2.xml
file2.ack*

What I have to do:

- **Move a .xml file only if the corresponding .ack is created**.

The difficult part: file names are random and I have no control over them.

Is there a way to create a .bat or a powershell to check and move with these requirements run at scheduled times?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: -1 as you are confusing SO with a free code writing servce; you should try it on your own and ask a specific question when you're stuck...

Answer (score 0):

the ideal would be a powershell task, indeed. Now, you will want to leverage window's *Scheduled Tasks* in order to run it at a scheduled time.

In a nutshell, what you'll have to do with powershell is to

- List the xml files in your folder with `Get-ChildItem  -filter "*.xml"`
- Pipe it to a `Where-Object` statement to make sure the .xml has a .ack counterpart, leveraging `Test-Path`
- For each produced item, move the .xml file.

  `Move-Item -Path $source -Destination $target`

Optionally, you could also clean the .ack files with `Remove-Item`.

Answer (score 0):

Find every filename that appears with two extensions, and move them both.

```
gci | group basename |? Count -eq 2 | select -expand group | move -Dest c:\temp
```

Because it's fun not to use any loops. If you want loops, maybe: to move the XML and delete the .ack.

```
gci *.ack |% { move ($_.BaseName +'.xml') "c:\temp" ; rm $_ }
```